# WLAN QoS setting: WMM vs SSID?

Tags: networking, wifi, local-area-network, qos

I've got a ZTE router which has Wireless LAN QoS setting `WMM` and `SSID` where `SSID` is the default. What should `SSID` mean here?

See attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of QoS settings.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @akostadinov's answer:
"One can create multiple SSIDs in the router. Then assign a different QoS value for each SSID."

The SSID here means that you'll have the QoS set based on the SSID priority value.

https://fccid.io/Q78-ZXW3512C/User-Manual/User-Manual-1928235
And according to the manual, it's simply that higher number will have higher priority, not 0-1 for background and etc.

"SSID Name
Set a name for this SSID. A name is composed of 1–32
characters.
Priority
Set the SSID priority ranging from 0 to 7. The default value
is 0, indicating no priority is set. A greater value indicates
a higher priority."

Comment: The question is about the meaning of the QoS options.

Comment: @RalfFriedl opps, was reading the other answer and post this one, missing some info .

Answer (score 2):

I found [answer](https://www.kaskus.co.id/thread/5a8811ca32e2e610098b4569/cara-setting-wmm-qos-zte-f609/) in another language (thanks google translate). Basically one can create multiple SSIDs in the router. Then assign a different QoS value for each SSID.

<del>There is a list with the meaning of each priority number, e.g. for video, background, etc. It is not that `x` is better or worse than `x+1`. So check the table as to what value to set.</del>

On a more careful read I see that from 0 to 7 priority is increasing as Đặng Quốc Trung pointed out.